# Filter and get data from JSON

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to get the data `value` from the `list`, the `size` of the array, the main thing is not through the index, because the order of the arrays can change and I can get specific data from the `code === "size"`. Unfortunately, the structure cannot be changed. It came to mind only through the `filter`, by index, but it is impossible

The result should be `100 150`

https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.b10638604c214b189f87747414e06035

```
[
  [
    "color",
    {
      "name": "Цвет",
      "code": "color",
      "list": [
        {
          "value": "Зеленый"
        },
        {
          "value": "Красный"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    "size",
    {
      "name": "Размер",
      "code": "size",
      "list": [
        {
          "value": "100"
        },
        {
          "value": "150"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: What did yo utry?

Comment: @0stone0 i write, that i try with filter by index, but i undestand that not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This data structure is terrible, but a quick fix could be something like this

```js
 const data = [
    
      [
        "color",
        {
          "name": "Цвет",
          "code": "color",
          "list": [
            {
              "value": "Зеленый"
            },
            {
              "value": "Красный"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      [
        "size",
        {
          "name": "Размер",
          "code": "size",
          "list": [
            {
              "value": "100"
            },
            {
              "value": "150"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    ]
    
    const size = data.filter(element => element[1].code === 'size')[0][1].list.map(element => element.value)
    
    console.log(size)
```